# I am writing a program that must accept input from the user

Tags: python

[When I say true it answers and asks another question.When I say false it it answers and asks another question. That is what it has to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbKKF.png)

[When I say i dont know and it just asks another question but I want it to say:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgoD7.png)

Comment: Include your code as text in the question! Others wont type it out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a  fairly simple example of user input being fed into a somewhat functional python3 script to control a MCU.](http://pastebin.com/MH67v1HR)

```
in0 = input('What is your name?: ')
while 1:
    C = input('Hello, ' + in0 + ', Please enter a command: ')
    if C == 'R11':

        os.system('clear')
        print(C + ', executed!')
        <ETC>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a simple program for adding two values in python. Here, I'm using the input function, just as your question states:

```
#Python program for addition of two values using input function.
a=int(input("Enter the 1st number: "))
b=int(input("Enter the 2nd number: "))
result = a + b
print("The result is: ", result)
```

I hope this helps you understand how we can enable the user to enter values in our code.